# How can i get children Item from Item using Sitecore ItemService?

Tags: sitecore-api, item-web-api

How can I get Children item using the Item service API?

I retrieved parent item and fields using Item service API

I got the result like below Json

```
{
  "ItemID": "25a40733-babf-4f16-a025-a3ffb0c84c05",
  "ItemName": "itemName",
  "ItemPath": "/sitecore/content/Home",
  "ParentID": "59b7047e-1063-4f2e-a452-4ca466ecb621",
  "TemplateID": "3191fecf-905e-4ca1-a007-05ba9f5b7455",
  "TemplateName": "templatename",
  "CloneSource": null,
  "ItemLanguage": "en",
  "ItemVersion": "1",
  "DisplayName": "testuser",
  "HasChildren": "True",
}
```

in the above result have "HasChildren": "True", but I cannot able to get the whole children value.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation

> https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/the-restful-api-for-the-itemservice.html

you can use url like

```
/item/{id}/children?database&language&version&includeStandardTemplateFields&includeMetadata&fields
```

to retrieve children of the item with id specified in `{id}` parameter

Comment: Thanks Marek. Working fine.

Comment: one more question can you help me.

Comment: I'm sure he can as soon as you open a new question.